# Writing a script that implements the following design

Tags: oracle, ddl

I wrote this code and I don't know why I am getting error

*Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name*

```
Create table downloads
(
 download_id   int Primary Key NOT NULL,
 User_id       int,
 download_date date,
 filename      Varchar(20),
 product_id    int,
 CONSTRAINT fk_column FOREIGN KEY (USER_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
);
```

Comment: `user` cannot be used as a table name unless quoted(such as `"user"`) as being a reserved keyword. Btw, using `NOT NULL` next to `Primary Key` is redundant.

Comment: Also, note that quoting table, column, or other object names is generally considered to be a bad practice in Oracle, as you are then forced to always use quotes when referencing that object. It is far better to avoid reserved keywords in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a table named "user".
please remove the line "CONSTRAINT fk_column FOREIGN KEY (USER_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),"
and use the below:

```
Create table downloads2
(
 download_id   int Primary Key NOT NULL,
 User_id       int,
 download_date date,
 filename      Varchar(20),
 product_id    int,
 FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES departments(department_id)
);
```